# Comment « re » + « partir » se fédèrent-ils sémantiquement pour signifier « répliquer » ?

Tags: étymologie

Quelles notions sémantiques sous-tendent « re » +  « partir » avec « riposter  [aussitôt à un propos](https://cnrtl.fr/definition/repartir) » ? [repartee (n.)](https://www.etymonline.com/word/repartee#etymonline_v_12818)

> 1640s, "quick remark," from French repartie "an answering blow or thrust" (originally a fencing term), noun use of fem. past participle of Old French repartir "to reply promptly, start out again,"
> from re- "back" (see [re-](https://www.etymonline.com/word/re-) + partir "to divide, separate, set out,"
> from Latin partiri "to share, part, distribute, divide,"
> from pars "a part, piece, a share" (from PIE root [*pere-](https://www.etymonline.com/word/*pere-) (2) "to grant, allot").
> In 17c. often spelled reparty (see [-ee](https://www.etymonline.com/word/-ee)). Meaning "a series of sharp rejoinders exchanged" is from 1680s.

Comment: @Maroon How's "ultimately a question about English etymology"? The semantic shift happened in French.

Comment: Sorry, I should have looked more carefully. The motivation was the English meaning, it seemed, which is fine, but in some cases such questions end being better suited for a site like English SE imo. Here it seems fine, being that the meaning also exists in French.

Comment: @Maroon No problem. I'm sorry too if my comment above felt gruff. Enchantée!

Comment: C'est le monde de l'oralité : « Ah dit donc, à peine l'évènement survenu, X est *parti* pour une bordée d'insultes à Y, ça *repart* aussi sec dans l'autre sens, et là, ça fait mouche, ça lui a cloué l'bec à X ». L'attaque est *partie* de la bouche de X (pour entrer dans les oreilles de Y qui sait quoi répondre), la réponse cinglante est *repartie* de la bouche de Y, … avec l'image de propos écrit : la lettre *envoyée* à  Y est *renvoyée* corrigée/annotée aussitôt à X ; le retour, la répartie  doit clore le dialogue ou y mettre un terme. Seuls les mots agressifs partent,et repartent en réponse.

Answer (score 1):

Le sens de "repartir" n'est pas aussi éloigné de "partir" qu'il le semble: "partir" signifie étymologiquement "mettre à part", d'où l'idée d'éloignement ou de séparation qui induit ensuite le sens courant de ce verbe.

Donc, avec "repartir", on voit la notion d'affirmation réitérée d'une divergence dans la discussion, faisant référence au sens étymologique de "partir", ou de prolongement du fil de la discussion, faisant référence au sens courant.